# Unwanted linebreaks when printing from Python and using utf-8 in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, cmd

I am working with strings from 8 languages and when debugging it's handy to print stuff to the console. I've had encoding errors but I got around them using `chcp 65001`

The problem now is that whenever there are unicode characters in printed text, part of the text gets carried on to the next line.

For example: "Día Mágico de San Valentín" goes out like this:

```
Día Mágico de San Valentín
n
```

the more unicode characters, the more characters are copied to the next line. Using `sys.stdout.write` prints the text in one line... until i print a linebreak. After a linebreak immediately same thing happens. I assume that Python passes some buffer length value to cmd that is wrong because unicode characters use more than 1 byte per char but I have no idea where to go from here :/

Comment: CMD can be started in unicode mode. See `cmd /?`.

Comment: That sets cmd's output to become unicode, doesn't help my issue at all. Still a nice thing to know.

Comment: In my experience and that of many others, code page 65001 is buggy and not really usable.  There is an issue on the CPython tracker to improve how Python uses the cmd.exe console with unicode.  In the meanwhile, you may do better running your code from an Idle editor, perhaps using Lucide Sans Unicode font.